# How do you add a custom network to the Gnosis Safe UI?

Tags: private-blockchain, hardhat, gnosis-safe, safe-apps-sdk

As the title suggests, I want to use the Gnosis Safe UI with a private network such as Hardhat.

How can I make this happen?

Example:
I want to interact with a smart contract from my own frontend using my deployed Safe. I know if I deployed it to a supported network by the Safe UI I'd be able to use the `safe-apps-sdk`, but I have to use a custom network that isn't supported.

1. How can I interact with it programmatically using JavaScript with my Safe?
2. How can I make it happen if I can't use the `safe-apps-sdk` to do so?
3. Am I able to copy the entire Safe UI and deploy it elsewhere to then add the custom network I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use our https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure repository to run your private network locally.

see [docs](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md) for more details

Comment: Is it possible to run safe-wallet-app locally and connect it to a remote safe-infrastructure? I could not find where the api url is configured.